# Problems assigning dict values to variables

Tags: python, csv

I am struggling with something that must be one of those 'it is so obvious I am an idiot' problems.  I have a csv file that I want to read in and use to create individual 'tables'.  I have a variable (RID) that marks the beginning of a new 'table'.

I can't get my indicator variable (currentRow) to advance as I finish manipulating each line.  You can see the print statements, currentRow remains equal to 0.
But if I use an assignment statement outside of the loop I can change the value of currentRow at will.  The test assignment is to just understand where I am getting in the loop.

```
currentRow=0
test=0
theTables=defaultdict(list)
for line in csv.DictReader(open(r'c:\temp\testread.csv')):
    newTableKey=line['CIK']+'-'+line['RDATE']+'-'+line['CDATE']+'-'+line['FNAME']+' '+line['TID']

    if line['RID']=='1':
        test+=1 # I can get here
        if currentRow>int(line['RID']):
            print 'got here'

            theTables[oldTableKey]=theList
            test+=1  # I cannot get here
        theList=[]
    theList.append(line)
    currrentRow=int(line['RID'])
    print currentRow  #this value always prints at 0
    print int(line['RID']) #this prints at the correct value
    oldTableKey=newTableKey
```

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but where does `row['RID']` come from? I don't see a `row` variable anywhere else but that line.

Comment: each row is a dictionary, there is a key called RID in the row (a column heading)

Comment: There is something wrong with your code sample. You are printing `int(row['RID'])` which is not assigned to anywhere in the code. If it is a typo and you print int(line['RID']) and it differs from what is assigned to currentRow, then you have not inserted all of your code; in particular you omitted something significant which modifies  currentRow again after assignment.

Also, could you include the CSV format?

Comment: I'll correct it, In my changing things around I went from row as the iterator coming from the DictReader to line

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the line:

```
currrentRow=int(line['RID'])
```

you have **three** `r`s in `currrentRow`. Reduce them to just two, and things should improve.

Comment: Thanks Alex I knew it was one of these types of problems, public humiliation is good for the soul.

Cheers

Comment: And run pylint or similar tools over the code so you don't have to ask Alex to review your code each time. ;-)  See http://infinitemonkeycorps.net/docs/pph/#id3

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to add the following somewhere inside the loop:

```
currentRow += 1
```

However, a better solution may be to use enumerable:

```
for currentRow, line in csv.DictReader..:
    stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like it's possible that `theTables[oldTableKey]=theList` could be executed with an uninitialized value of `oldTableKey`.